# Opacity problem with Carto static maps API V1 and .JPG image type

Tags: carto

**EDIT**

If I change the last three characters of the image request URL to be `png` instead of `jpg`, then the image renders nicely.

**Original question**

A few years ago, my Carto anonymous map was rendering nicely, like this:

[image: image with basemap]

Since around October 2020, the images have been coming out like the black image below from the long-standing production instance.  Now that we're interested in fixing it, it turns out they're also coming out like this when the image generation runs on my local machine.

[image: image without basemap]

The code creating the maps hasn't changed.  The data behind the yellow lines has been updated, but since the yellow lines still look right, I can't imagine how that might be the cause.

I create the anonymous map by posting some JSON, which starts like this (I also tried a few other free basemap templates, all with the same result):

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "name": "boundary",
  "layers": [
    {
        "type": "http",
        "options": {
            "urlTemplate": "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
        }
    },
    {
      "type": "cartodb",
      "options": {
        "cartocss_version": "2.3.0",
```

The URL to get the image looks like this:

```cs
string template = @"https://{0}/api/v1/map/static/center/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}/{6}.jpg?api_key={7}";

var url = string.Format(template,
    cartoDbDomain, //0
    layerGroupId, //1
    zoom, //2
    boundingBox.LatitudeCentre, //3
    boundingBox.LongitudeCentre, //4
    width, //5
    height, //6
    apiKey); //7
```

Is there something wrong with the JSON or the code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to relate to cartodb.com.  We happen to have our own Carto server, hosted completely separately from cartodb.com.  If I use that server, I can get images like this:

[image: Image generated using our own instance of Carto]

This image was generated using cartodb.com, using an otherwise-identical process:

[image: Image generated using cartodb.com]

I'll try to get in touch with the folks at Carto to find out if there were any breaking changes to the V1 API around October 2020.